# Python: Class factory using user input as class names

Tags: python, metaprogramming, factory, metaclass

I want to add class atttributes to a superclass dynamically. Furthermore, I want to create classes that inherit from this superclass dynamically, and the name of those subclasses should depend on user input.

There is a superclass "Unit", to which I can add attributes at runtime. This already works.

```
def add_attr (cls, name, value):
    setattr(cls, name, value)

class Unit(object):
    pass

class Archer(Unit):
    pass

myArcher = Archer()
add_attr(Unit, 'strength', 5)
print "Strenght ofmyarcher: " + str(myArcher.strength)
Unit.strength = 2
print "Strenght ofmyarcher: " + str(myArcher.strength)
```

This leads to the desired output:
Strenght ofmyarcher: 5
Strenght ofmyarcher: 2

But now I don't want to predefine the subclass Archer, but I'd rather let the user decide how to call this subclass. I've tried something like this:

```
class Meta(type, subclassname):
    def __new__(cls, subclassname, bases, dct):
    return type.__new__(cls, subclassname, Unit, dct)

factory = Meta()    
factory.__new__("Soldier")
```

but no luck. I guess I haven't really understood what **new** does here.
What I want as a result here is

```
class Soldier(Unit):
    pass
```

being created by the factory. And if I call the factory with the argument "Knight", I'd like a class Knight, subclass of Unit, to be created.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!
Bye
-Sano

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To create a class from a name, use the `class` statement and assign the name. Observe:

```
def meta(name):
    class cls(Unit):
        pass

    cls.__name__ = name
    return cls
```

Now I suppose I should explain myself, and so on. When you create a class using the class statement, it is done dynamically-- it is equivalent of calling [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type).

For example, the following two snippets do the same thing:

```
class X(object): pass
X = type("X", (object,), {})
```

The name of a class-- the first argument to type-- is assigned to `__name__`, and that's basically the end of that (the only time `__name__` is itself used is probably in the default `__repr__()` implementation). To create a class with a dynamic name, you can in fact call type like so, or you can just change the class name afterward. The `class` syntax exists for a reason, though-- it's convenient, and it's easy to add to and change things later. If you wanted to add methods, for example, it would be

```
class X(object):
    def foo(self): print "foo"

def foo(self): print "foo"
X = type("X", (object,), {'foo':foo})
```

and so on. So I would advise using the class statement-- if you had known you could do so from the beginning, you likely would have done so. Dealing with `type` and so on is a mess.

(You should not, by the way, call `type.__new__()` by hand, only `type()`)

Comment: Thank you Devin! Both your and Felix' solution seem to have a side effect I haven't considered: The new class is an object and needs to be hooked to something - stored in a varibale or appended to a list or something. I can't just create the Knight class and then call the constructor with myKnight = Knight(). Rather, I have to do something like this:
unitlist.append(meta("Knight"))
myKnight = unitlist[0]()

Is there a way arround this? To put it bluntly: Save the Knight class at the same "general position" the Unit class is saved when it's definition is reached in the code?

Comment: @Sano98: I'm really not sure what you mean. You can do `Knight = meta("Knight")` and then do `myKnight = Knight()`. What do you want, exactly?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want to do! Simply save it under Knight... And then it's in the global namespace and I can use the class as if it was hardcoded. Great, thank you. Just didn't think I could call      Knight() when saving the class as     Knight, but sure, why not?

Comment: Looking back on this, I'd like to note that Felix's idea of giving a "name attribute" is probably the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html) builtin function.

```
knight_class = type('Knight', (Unit,), {})
```

- First parameter: Name of new class
- Second parameter: Tuple of parent classes
- Third parameter: dictionary of class attributes.

But in your case, if the subclasses don't implement a different behaviour, maybe giving the `Unit` class a `name` attribute is sufficient.

Comment: I found your answer very helpful.  Thanks for adding it in spite of the others already being there!