# Python class factory with variable attribute names

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I am creating a Django application, and during development I have created many classes which have a very similar structure, e.g.:

```
class OneAPIListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.One.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OneSerializer
    filter_class = OneFilterSet

class TwoAPIListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Two.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TwoSerializer
    filter_class = TwoFilterSet

...
class <Name>APIListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.<Name>.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.<Name>Serializer
    filter_class = <Name>FilterSet
```

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically generate these classes from the list of strings `["One", "Two", ..., <Name>]`. I see that there are metaclasses in other SO questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461751/python-class-factory-using-user-input-as-class-names), e.g. I could do something like

```
<Name> = type(<Name> + "APIListView", (generics.ListAPIView,), {'queryset' : ???})
```

But I am not sure what to put into `???` in my case since the variable is part of an object name.

Comment: Just put `{'queryset': getattr(models, name).objects.all()}` and so on.

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with *metaclasses*, which is a different thing.  Though programmatic creation of classes that match some pattern could be considered *metaprogramming*.  You could also in principle write a metaclass that does this but from your description there's no need for the extra complication that entails.

Comment: thank you, I did not know about getattr and it looks like it works well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `{'queryset': getattr(models, name).objects.all()}` and so on.  [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) is important to know about if you're going to be doing any kind of metaprogramming.  Occasionally [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) as well but less often, especially if you're just building classes with `type(...)`.